# Making Emacs show the last part of bash-command output

Tags: evil, display, bash

I use the Evil mode inside Emacs for doing a lot of my work. If I need to run a shell-command and see its output all I need to do is type in normal mode `:!<bash command>`. The window splits into two halves and displays
the output in another buffer named *Shell Command Output*

However, I notice that when the output is very long (say when one compiles a program) the output buffer shows the top part of the output rather than the bottom part which is where the compilation errors are usually mentioned, and are of immediate interest during programming.

How do I get Emacs to display the ending of the bash command output on running the bash command?

Comment: How about using the built in compile mechanism?:  `(setq compilation-scroll-output t)` -- `M-x compile` and then whatever command-line suits your needs.

Comment: Perfect! If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the built-in compile mechanism:  set the variable `compilation-scroll-output` to a non-nil value with `(setq compilation-scroll-output t)`; type `M-x compile`; and use whatever command-line is needed.