# How to make *Shell Command Output* buffer scroll to the end?

Tags: buffers, shell, shell-command

I often execute shell commands via `M-!` and their output is then shown in the buffer `*Shell Command Output*`. How can I make this buffer display the *end* (rather than the beginning) so that I can see whether the shell command successfully terminated?

I saw [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46212/making-emacs-show-the-last-part-of-bash-command-output) that when compiling via `M-x compile`, one can use `(setq compilation-scroll-output t)` to display the end of the compilation buffer. That behaviour would be great for `*Shell Command Output*`.

Comment: The compilation library can be used for many things beyond compiling a program, e.g., grep, or execute just any old program such as print the date.  Here is an example:  `(let ((compilation-scroll-output t)) (compile "while :; do echo \"Hello-World\"; sleep 1; done"))`

Comment: So you are essentially suggesting to rather work with `M-x compile` in this case?

Comment: In a nutshell, "yes" that is my suggestion.  It is certainly possible to put some time and effort into the function `shell-command` to make it behave as you desire.  There are several variations of how that function operates depending upon the circumstances ... Someone may be inclined to write-up a solution for you ... this question; however, is (in my opinion) an exact duplicate of the linked thread ... which has a solution that may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Interesting thoughts. At first, I thought that I want an answer to this, but then I realized that `M-x compile` in this case is also a bit more consistent in how I use it in other cases. Also, I often use `M-!` to create a new file (`touch foo.txt`) and there is no need to show the buffer in this case, for example (which would probably require a bit of work as you say). So, nice, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs 26.1 provides the `shell-command-dont-erase-buffer` option, if you set it to `end-last-out`, `M-!` moves the point to the end of the output, however, it won't delete the previous commands' outputs, unlike the default behavior.

```
(setq shell-command-dont-erase-buffer 'end-last-out)
```